# Create another "Featured Image" picker wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, image

I already have a Featured Image picker on my Wordpress that chooses the image to be shown on the front page of my site.  BUT, I want another image picker just like the featured image picker because I would like the authors to easily choose a image that should be shown at the top of the article.

The reason for this is that I want to show an ad after the title, excerpt and a second image. And this second image needs to be chosen somehow, and the best way is to do it the same way as a featured image.

But, I dont know where to begin with creatin such an "widget" for the "New post"-editor.

I know both HTML, CSS og PHP, so the programming aint a barrier, I just dont know where to start.

Best regards,
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a WordPress plugin to [create multiple featured images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-featured-image/), if you would like to go the plugin route. However, I might recommend creating a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types), which would allow you to specifically add a secondary image to your post under the title of "Advertisement" or something along those lines. The programming isn't difficult and there are [many](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/complete-guide-custom-post-types/) [great](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-your-first-wordpress-custom-post-type) [tutorials](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-use-custom-post-types/) available on the subject.